# Problems with multi-filter wikidata sparql query not seeming to work properly

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to generate a list of former counties and county equivalents in the United States, but the query isn't returning what I would otherwise expect.

My test case is [Illinois County, Virginia](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q14687596).

[My query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcounty%20%3FcountyLabel%20%3FstateLabel%20%3Fpage_titleEN%20%3Fcoordinate_location%20%3Finception%20%3Fdissolved%20%3Frole%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcounty%20%28wdt%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2a%29%29%20wd%3AQ47168%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2a%29%29%20wd%3AQ1620908.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcounty%20wdt%3AP131%20%3Fstate.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcounty%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aname%20%3Fpage_titleEN.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcounty%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoordinate_location.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcounty%20wdt%3AP571%20%3Finception.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Finception%20wdt%3Ap2868%20%3Frole.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcounty%20wdt%3AP576%20%3Fdissolved.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%28%3FcountyLabel%29) is intended to grab all instances and subclasses of county or county equivalents, as well as instances or subclasses of historical regions. Unfortunately, while the query returns some items of interest, it does not return Illinois County, Virginia.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?county ?countyLabel ?stateLabel ?page_titleEN ?coordinate_location ?inception ?dissolved ?role WHERE {
  ?county (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q47168;
    (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q1620908.
  OPTIONAL { ?county wdt:P131 ?state. }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?article schema:about ?county;
      schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>;
      schema:name ?page_titleEN.
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?county wdt:P625 ?coordinate_location. }
  OPTIONAL { ?county wdt:P571 ?inception. }
  OPTIONAL { ?inception wdt:p2868 ?role. }
  OPTIONAL { ?county wdt:P576 ?dissolved.}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY (?countyLabel)
```

I was expecting Illinois County, Virginia to be returned, as it is both a subclass of County and County Equivalents in the United States (wd:Q47168), as well as a subclass of Historical Regions (wd:Q1620908).

Comment: You're visiting the *Wikidata Truthy* dump "issue": each statement has an associated rank: preferred rank, normal rank, deprecated rank. The default value is normal rank but everybody can change the rank to one of the other values. The "truthy" data dump does not contain any statements with deprecated rank and if there are statements with normal and preferred rank, only the statements with preferred rank are in the dump. When using `wdt:` prefix only the truthy data is queried. And in your *"Illinois county"* example the statement being preferred is "administrative division".

Comment: you can see a rewritten query sketch using all statements: `SELECT DISTINCT ?county ?countyLabel {
  ?county (p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q47168;
    (p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q1620908.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY (?countyLabel)` - this returns *"Illinois county"* as well. You can see I used `p:P31/ps:p31` which reflects the Wikidata data model, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format